# syntax error for "AUTO_INCREMENT" - Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, auto-increment

`SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT" LINE 1: ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000; ^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000`

I want my `id` column to start from `1000` & being `AUTO INCREMENT` . Below given is given migrations page. I'm getting the above given error while migrating. I'm using Laravel-8 & Pgsql-13 . Any help to solve this is much appreciated.

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('order_userId')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('order_userId')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->float('orderTotal');
                $table->integer('createdBy')->unsigned();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
            DB::update("ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $table->id()->startingValue(1000);
```

This should do the job . supported from Laravel version 8 and above.